# realloc() seems to affect already allocated memory

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I am experiencing an issue where the invocation of `realloc` seems to modify the contents of another string, `keyfile`.

It's supposed to run through a null-terminated `char*` (keyfile), which contains just above 500 characters. The problem, however, is that the `reallocation` I perform in the `while`-loop seems to modify the contents of the keyfile.

I tried removing the dynamic reallocation with `realloc` and instead initialize the pointers in the `for`-loop with a size of `200*sizeof(int)` instead. The problem remains, the `keyfile` string is modified during the (re)allocation of memory, and I have no idea why. I have confirmed this by printing the keyfile-string before and after both the `malloc` and `realloc` statements.

Note: The keyfile only contains the characters `a-z`, no digits, spaces, linebreaks or  uppercase. Only a text of 26, lowercase letters.

```
int **getCharMap(const char *keyfile) {

    char *alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int **charmap = malloc(26*sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        charmap[(int) alphabet[i]]    = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
        charmap[(int) alphabet[i]][0] = 0; // place a counter at index 0
    }


    int letter;
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char c = keyfile[count];
    while (c != '\0') {
        int arr_count = charmap[c][0]; 
        arr_count++; 

        charmap[c] = realloc(charmap[c], (arr_count+1)*sizeof(int));

        charmap[c][0] = arr_count; 
        charmap[c][arr_count] = count; 

        c = keyfile[++count];  
    }



    // Just inspecting the results for debugging        
    printf("\nCHARMAP\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        letter = (int) alphabet[i];
        printf("%c: ", (char) letter);
        int count = charmap[letter][0];

        printf("%d", charmap[letter][0]);
        if (count > 0) {
            for (int j = 1; j < count+1; j++) {
                printf(",%d", charmap[letter][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    exit(0);

    return charmap;
}
```

Comment: valgrind valgrind valgrind

Comment: Should be `int **charmap = malloc(26*sizeof(int*))` in case you're running over a 64-bit system (or in the rare case of a 32-bit system with 16-bit registers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
charmap[(int) alphabet[i]]    = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
charmap[(int) alphabet[i]][0] = 0; // place a counter at index 0
```

You are writing beyond the end of your `charmap` array. So, you are invoking undefined behaviour and it's not surprising that you are seeing weird effects.

You are using the character codes as an index into the array, but they do not start at 0! They start at whatever the ASCII code for `a` is.

You should use `alphabet[i] - 'a'` as your array index.

Comment: You should also include the error pointed out by @barakmanos in the comments.

Comment: This was what I needed, and such a clever solution as well. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code is a source of troubles:

```
int **charmap = malloc(26*sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    charmap[...] = ...;
```

---

If `sizeof(int) < sizeof(int*)`, then it will be performing illegal memory access operations.

For example, on 64-bit platforms, the case is usually `sizeof(int) == 4 < 8 == sizeof(int*)`.

Under that scenario, by writing into `charmap[13...25]`, you will be accessing unallocated memory.

---

Change this:

```
int **charmap = malloc(26*sizeof(int));
```

To this:

```
int **charmap = malloc(26*sizeof(int*));
```

Comment: ... or `int **charmap = malloc(26 * sizeof *charmap);`.

Comment: @chux: Once again - thanks for enlightening me. I do agree on using the symbol name in this case, so that the initialization is independent of the variable type.